# adding another hover function on top of 2 others

Tags: css

I want to add a small description at the bottom of the box after I hover. Like this:

[image]

I've already got the title sliding down from top and images sliding towards the center. But I want to add another description that slides from bottom to up. (I made the bottom text effect with photoshop to show what I mean).

Code so far:

```css
 #box{
        margin-top:200px;
        margin-left:80px;
        width:1200px;
        left: 40px;
        right:100px;
        }

    .base{
        position:relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:335px;
        height: 265px;
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
        margin-left:55px;
        margin-bottom:75px;
        background-color: #fef9f9;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px #dcdcdc;
    }
        
    .name {position:relative;
        color:#bbb;
        font-family: anton;
        font-size:25px;
        letter-spacing: 0px;
        text-align:center;
        width:330px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #fff;
        margin-top: -35px;
        z-index:4;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
    .base:hover .name {margin-top: 0px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
    .base img{
        width:270px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left:21px;
        margin-top:21px;
        padding:10px;
        border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
        background:#fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px #dcdcdc;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
    .base img {position: absolute;}
    .dude1{
        opacity:0;
        position:relative;
        left:-90px;
        z-index:1;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
    .dude1 img {    width:130px;}
    .base:hover .dude1{
        left:0px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        opacity:1;}
    .dude2{
        opacity:0;
        position:relative;
        left:230px;
        z-index:1;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
    .dude2 img {width:130px;}
    .base:hover .dude2{
        left:140px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        opacity:1;}
        
    #s-m-t-tooltip {
        display: block;
        background: #ccc;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-family: calibri;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 18px;
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        min-width: 40px;
        max-width: 200px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.3);
        z-index: 99999;
    }
```

```html
<div class="base"> 
<img src="http://i1242.photobucket.com/albums/gg524/ichimango-suki/Tumblr/takayama_zps605c58e9.jpg"/></a>
<div class="dude1">
<img src="http://i1242.photobucket.com/albums/gg524/ichimango-suki/Tumblr/takayama-yuya_zpsf71d1421.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="dude2">
<img src="http://i1242.photobucket.com/albums/gg524/ichimango-suki/Tumblr/takayama-yama_zps97c309f6.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="name">TAKAYAMA
</div></div></div></div>
```

How do I add it?

Comment: please add a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#box {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  width: 1200px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 100px;
}
.base {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 335px;
  height: 265px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  background-color: #fef9f9;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px #dcdcdc;
}
.name {
  position: relative;
  color: #bbb;
  font-family: anton;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 330px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #fff;
  margin-top: -35px;
  z-index: 4;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.base:hover .name {
  margin-top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.base img {
  width: 270px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 21px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px #dcdcdc;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px #dcdcdc;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.base img {
  position: absolute;
}
.dude1 {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: -90px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.dude1 img {
  width: 130px;
}
.base:hover .dude1 {
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
.dude2 {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 230px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.dude2 img {
  width: 130px;
}
.base:hover .dude2 {
  left: 140px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
#s-m-t-tooltip {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-family: calibri;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 18px;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.3);
  z-index: 99999;
}
.desc {
  font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.base:hover .desc{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <img src="http://i1242.photobucket.com/albums/gg524/ichimango-suki/Tumblr/takayama_zps605c58e9.jpg" />
  </a>
  <div class="dude1">
    <img src="http://i1242.photobucket.com/albums/gg524/ichimango-suki/Tumblr/takayama-yuya_zpsf71d1421.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dude2">
    <img src="http://i1242.photobucket.com/albums/gg524/ichimango-suki/Tumblr/takayama-yama_zps97c309f6.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="name">TAKAYAMA
  </div>
  <div class="desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. i tried to do this but ended up getting some things wonked up. it works now. thanks for your help.